# Best practice to construct a DOM object from a long string of html codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using an Ajax json to return a string of html codes from a webmethod (asp.net). The string (data.d) can be substantially long with thousands of html codes.

```
success: function (data) {
if (data.d != "") { 
// create result.aspx page from data.d that contains html codes (thousands of characters)
}
```

My result.aspx page works fine. I'm counting on the browser to parse the html output. However I've learned that this is weak programming and that I should parse data.d before constructing the DOM object.

What is the best practice to do so? and is it necessary to parse or process data.d before constructing the DOM obect since all modern browsers will do it anyway!!!

All pieces of advice are well appreciated!

Comment: You seem to be confusing too many concepts. Maybe provide some background to the actual usage of this, such as: is this supposed to replace partial content in an existing page? is there anything "interesting" to know about the content of the string (other than being long)?

Comment: Well if that string is in encoded format then you should decode it before you are going to inject it in the dom.

Comment: The content of the string is basically pure html codes returned from a webmethod that constructs its content based on data from an SQL database. The string contains html tags only. Once received by Ajax json I want to inject it in the DOM to create the content of my result.aspx page....

Comment: And if it's not encoded (opposed to what Jai suggested), then i don't see what the difficulty is, or what you're trying to solve / prevent. In fact with jQuery (that you apparently use) you could've used the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should treat data as unsafe, and avoid executing it in the browser.

One can for example send only the data and build the elements in the browser. By putting the data as text in elements, you avoid executing the data. Anything that you put in the element as text will just be treated as text and not executed. Example:

```
success: function (data) {
  if (data.d != "") {
    $('.result').append($('<div>', { text: data.d }));
  }
}
```

If you send HTML code from the server and insert the code in the page, then the code will be executed. You can do that, but that means that you move the responsibility for the safety of the code to the server. What the server returns have to be safe to execute, so any data that it uses to genereate the code has to be verified or encoded depending on where the data comes from.

If you for example fetch a list of comments from different users, there is an obvious risk for cross scripting attacks. Every value that originates from a user should be HTML encoded when you put the code together to prevent it from being executed as script. Example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Comment comment in comments) {
  builder
   .Append("<div class=\"comment\"><div class=\"name\">")
   .Append(Server.HtmlEncode(comment.UserName))
   .Append("</div><div class=\"text\">")
   .Append(Server.HtmlEncode(comment.Text))
   .Append("</div></div>");
}
string response = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.In fact all the html codes are written by a webmethod on the server. In fact the cycle goes as follows: 1- json sends variables to the webmethod on the server. 2- The webmethod connects to an SQL database to get data based on the variables. 3- the webmethod creates an html template and add those data. 4- The html string is sent back to the user....

Comment: @Gloria: Yes, that is a pretty common scenario, with just variations of how the code in step 3 is created. The risks to look out for is that someone can send a malicious request so that the variables sent to the server can't be trusted, and that there can be data in the database that was entered by users previously and thus can't be trusted.

Comment: Tack för svaret! The data in the database goes through 2 validations when it's posted by a user (the ASP.NET Input validation is enabled for the entire project, plus I'm also using the Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment for each input). Is that safe enough? I'm aware that there is no absolute safety but do I need to encode/decode as well and/or thake other precautions before injection the returned html string into the DOM...?

Comment: @Gloria: Input should generally be considered to be unsafe, but it's only harmful when you use it wrong. If you HTML encode the text when you place it in the HTML code then you don't need to do anything else to it. The input validation is supposed to remove harmful values, but frankly you only need it if you don't know how to handle the data correctly. The GetSafeHtmlFragment method is only needed if you want to allow users to use HTML code instead of HTML encoding the text to show it just as written.

Comment: OK I got the picture... I will take your advice in my next step. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*I should parse data.d before constructing the DOM object.*

Absolutely.

Because the string could be encoded<sup>1</sup> so before creating dom nodes you should always decode it and then you can build it.

a sample is below.

```js
var encodedStr = encodeURIComponent("<h1>What</h1>");
var decodedStr = decodeURIComponent(encodedStr);

var encoded = {"d":encodedStr};
var decoded = {"d":decodedStr};

var body1 = document.querySelector('#body1');
var body2 = document.querySelector('#body2');

body1.innerHTML = encoded.d;
body2.innerHTML = decoded.d;
```

```html
<p>Encoded one:</p>
<div id='body1'></div>
<br/><br/>
<p>Decoded one:</p>
<div id='body2'></div>
```

<sub>**1:** It would be better to save the encoded html strings to prevent SQL injections.</sub>

Comment: Encoding the HTML doesn't prevent cross scripting attacks, as you are decoding it in the client code. If you want to prevent SQL injection, that doesn't have anything to do with how you sent the data between the server and the client.

Comment: yeah right but what i meant was while save in the db. @Guffa

Comment: Yes, that is my point. What you do to prevent SQL injection shouldn't reflect how you send the data to the browser.

Comment: In fact all the html codes are written by a webmethod on the server. In fact the cycle goes as follows: 1- json sends variables to the webmethod on the server. 2- The webmethod connects to an SQL database to get data based on the variables. 3- the webmethod creates an html template and add those data. 4- The html string is sent back to the user....